# Get available SSL/TLS protocols in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, openssl

Avoiding trial-and-error, I would like to list which TLS/SSL protocols are available for use on the system (in a cross-platform way).

Python `ssl` module offers constants such as:

```
ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv2
```

But these do not say anything about what the system actually supports when connecting to a server.

Additionally, is there a way to get from an `SSLContext` the supported protocols that will be used? 
For example SSLv2 and SSLv3 are disabled when using `ssl.create_default_contex()`, would it be possible to somehow parse the `SSLContext.options` to list which protocols *are* supported?

EDIT:
For example on the latest Debian TLSv1 is disabled and connecting to TLSv1-only hosts will fail, yet `ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1` is still available and also creating `ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)` works.

Comment: what makes you think that those constants "do not say anything about what the system actually supports when connecting to a server"?

Comment: Read about [SSL — An interface to the SSL-specific parts of OpenSSL](https://pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/ssl.html)

Comment: The documentation says: "Deprecated since version 2.7.13: OpenSSL has deprecated all version specific protocols. Use the default protocol with flags like OP_NO_SSLv3 instead."  https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html#ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_1 Also on for example in the latest Debian, TLSv1 is disabled, yet the PROTOCOL_TLSv1 is still there.